# Normalize.css does not fully add reset to react app

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, norm

I'm following the [instructions](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-css-reset) on Reacts official site here. I have an `index.css` file setup in the root of my `src` directory with the import as the say:

```
@import-normalize;
```

I then import the `index.css` file in my App component:

```
import '../../index.css';

class App {}
```

Though the stylesheet is indeed there, it only **partially** loads the reset instead of the full thing. I don't see an option in the docs to add/subtract what you want. Below you can see what is added. Now compare this to the [full reset](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/8.0.1/normalize.css).

```
/*! normalize.css v9.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/csstools/normalize.css */

/* Document
 * ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in
 *    IE on Windows Phone and in iOS.
 */

html {
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
}

/* Sections
 * ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
 * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
 */

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/* Grouping content
 * ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
 * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
 */

hr {
  box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
  height: 0; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

pre {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/* Text-level semantics
 * ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Add the correct text decoration in Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
 */

abbr[title] {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/**
 * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
 * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
 */

code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
 */

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/* Embedded content
 * ========================================================================== */

/* Forms
 * ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the margin in Safari.
 */

button,
input,
select {
  margin: 0;
}

/**
 * 1. Show the overflow in IE.
 * 2. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
 */

button {
  text-transform: none; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 */

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
}

/**
 * Correct the padding in Firefox.
 */

fieldset {
  padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
}

/**
 * 1. Add the correct display in Edge and IE.
 * 2. Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
 */

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
 */

select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
 * 2. Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE.
 */

textarea {
  margin: 0; /* 1 */
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
 * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
 */

[type="search"] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
 */

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/**
 * Correct the text style of placeholders in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
 */

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 0.54;
}

/**
 * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
 */

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
 * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
 * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
 */

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
  font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/**
 * Remove the inner border and padding of focus outlines in Firefox.
 */

::-moz-focus-inner {
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

/**
 * Restore the focus outline styles unset by the previous rule in Firefox.
 */

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/* Interactive
 * ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Add the correct display in Edge and IE.
 */

details {
  display: block;
}

/*
 * Add the correct styles in Edge, IE, and Safari.
 */

dialog {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  height: -moz-fit-content;
  height: -webkit-fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

dialog:not([open]) {
  display: none;
}

/*
 * Add the correct display in all browsers.
 */

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/* Scripting
 * ========================================================================== */

/* User interaction
 * ========================================================================== */
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two reasons (the second being the main one).

**1)** The first is due to the browserslist config in create react app. Postcss uses the browsers list configuration to determine which styles to keep/remove. The latest version of CRA uses this `browserslist` development config:

```
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
```

If you copy down the production config to development you'll see some of the styles added. For example, `overflow: visible;` being added to `hr` elements for Edge and IE. If you want a cleaner look on what will be included and aren't too far along in the project, run the build, and check out the `static/css/*main.randomletters.chunk` chunk file.

**2)** [Postcss-normalize doesn't actually point](https://github.com/csstools/postcss-normalize/blob/master/src/lib/cssMap.js#L12) at the necolas/normalize.css stylesheet you linked. Instead it points at [@csstools/normalize.css](https://github.com/csstools/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css). **Many of the differences you noticed will be there**. The author of postcss-normalize (who co-created normalize) says that this version is more actively maintained as the necolas/normalize version includes "non-fixes". I haven't looked into it enough to know whether they're actually non-fixes or not but you can see what he said here: https://github.com/csstools/normalize.css/issues/3. So feel free to `yarn remove normalize.css` if you had it installed!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So is there no way to configure the browserlist myself?

Comment: You can! If you used create-react-app, you should see the configuration in `package.json` which is yours to change. The [browserslist package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserslist) is neat because you can target it for general coverage based on browser usage stats per country, world, etc. or just by specific browser versions. If I'm on a project that requires maximum coverage, I usually find using `[>1%, ie>=latestYouNeedToSupport]` is plenty. More in the docs here: [https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist).